# GUI tool for packet replay

Tags: graphical-user-interface, packet-analyzer, tcpreplay

Is there a freeware Windows/Linux GUI packet replay tool that has the advanced features of tcpreplay (http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/) or bittwist (http://bittwist.sourceforge.net)? I'm particularly interested in the following features:

1. Open pcap files for editing and injecting into arbitrary network
2. Change source and destination addresses/ports of UDP packets
3. Change packet timing (with millisecond resolution)
4. Edit packet contents, including modifying its length
5. Has graphical front end for Windows or Linux (or Mac OS X)

I've scanned a couple lists of potential tools ([here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) and [here](http://www.grid.unina.it/software/ITG/link.php)), but nothing really fits my requirements. The closest tool might be Ostinato (http://code.google.com/p/ostinato/), but it doesn't appear to open packet capture files. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried Ostinato? The "Features" section on its page says "Open, edit, replay and save PCAP files".

Comment: Product recommendations, including if-exists recon, are off-topic per the [FAQ](http//serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

I always use Wireshark (formerly ethereal) for simple decode and analysis.  While the price is right (free) and the cross-platform GUI functional, the feature set does not meet your complete list.  There is also professional tool ($) from Fluke Networks called ClearSight™ Analyzer.  It will replay multimedia streams, etc from pcap files.

Answer (score 0):

[Ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net/index.php) might work for you. I have only played around with its basic features, but it will allow you to do packet injection into a packet stream and has a wide range of plug-ins available, some of which might be useful to you.

I don't know of anyway offhand to modify packets "on-the-fly" without already being a part of the tcp stream.

**EDIT:** Oh I forgot about ettercap filters... [filter video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HppWr3mKwW4)

Comment: Thanks. Ettercap looks useful, but it doesn't open pcap files or support changing the packet timing (although, I might be able to use the `exec` command to sleep between packets).

Comment: Before you dismiss it, I suggest you read through the manual. Like I said, I'm not that familiar with Ettercap but I think it can do most of what you want. Although, you'll probably have to combine some tools to get all the functionality you're looking for. Sorry, I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Ok, you're right: it can open pcap files. I don't see timing control. I might just have to roll my own GUI for tcpreplay.